# jQuery Datepicker - How can I format the date as an epoch timestamp (in seconds NOT milliseconds)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, epoch

I'm using the jquery datepicker plugin to set a date field that is stored as an epoch timestamp in the db (the field, publish_time, maps directly to the table schema).

It seems that Datepicker only supports epoch in milliseconds, and not seconds. Its aggravating that it supports milli & nano seconds, but not seconds.

Are there any quick workarounds?

```
// Setup datepicker
$('[name=datepicker-publish_time]').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'mm-dd-yy',
    altField : '[name=publish_time]',
     altFormat : '@'
});
```

References:
jQuery Datepicker - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate
jQuery Support Date Formats - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Edit: Below is a quick dirty solution...

```
$('[name=datepicker-publish_time]').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'mm-dd-yy',
    onSelect : function(dateText, inst)
    {
        var epoch = $.datepicker.formatDate('@', $(this).datepicker('getDate')) / 1000;

        $('[name=publish_time]').val(epoch);
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem... thanks for posting your solution. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the millisecond representation and parseInt to get an integer value. Then you can multiply with 1000 to get the seconds. This just requires a little processing instead of taking the value of the datepicker directly.

Comment: I'll have to do that as a last resort option. I'd need to write a custom callback, which I'm not against doing but I'm hoping there is an expression I can use in dateFormat (eg, '(@/1000)')

Answer (score 6):

I'm typing this as an answer and not a comment so it doesn't get missed: I caution strongly against using the raw timestamp from your client as a value to stuff into your database unless you're **really sure** that that's what you want to do.  Your clients may be in different time zones than your servers (in fact, in general there's roughly a 96% chance they are :-)  so when they pick "April 2" it may or may not end up as "April 2" in your database.

Sometimes of course you *want* the client time, but in my experience that's not too common.

Comment: I had a similar issue to the OP in that I needed to compare dates recorded by the user with a datepicker against the current server time... rather than save the millisecond value returned by tadepicker, as I also wanted to record a date string (DD d mm yy) I then used jquery ajax to send that string to a php script that rendered it as a unix timestamp server side and returned that